# Why can't I drag a UIView into my UIViewController in Interface Builder?

Tags: interface-builder

I have a UIViewController subclass. It currently has a UITableView in it.

I want the UITableView to be a subview of a UIView, so I can find the bottom of the screen and put an ad banner there.

When I drag a UIView onto the UIViewController, it won't go there. I can drop it in as a subview of the TableView, but that's not what I want. I can also get the UIView to drop in beside the FirstResponder and Exit, which doesn't seem right.

Screenshot shows the hierarchy in Interface Builder, and the definition of the UIViewController so you can see it's not a UITableViewController subclass.

[image]

Comment: because you need a base view. Try to add a UIVIew as the base view.